# ¿Cómo escribo en un archivo txt con CMD?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, terminal

Sé cómo hacerlo en Linux (bash), a "echo" le puedes pasar como argumento un archivo, luego en vez de escribir en la terminal lo hará en el susodicho archivo

```
touch archivo.txt

echo "ejemplo" > archivo.txt
```

El título ya explica qué quiero hacer con ésto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo exactamente igual a como has descrito para Linux.
En windows también existe el comando `echo` y la redirección con `>`

Puedes escribir en una ventana de commandos esto:

```
echo "hola mundo" > archivo.txt
```

Y te generará en ese mismo directorio un fichero `archivo.txt` con el contenido **"hola mundo"**.
Si deseas añadir texto un fichero ya existente, puedes usar esto `>>`:

```
echo "¿Cómo estás?" >> archivo.txt
```

Te añadirá ese texto al archivo anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir a la ruta donde quieres crear ese txt y hacer lo siguiente:

C:\Users\X\Desktop>copy con Prueba.txt (así creas el fichero txt)

Hola, soy un fichero de prueba (aquí el texto que quieres escribir en él)

Puedo continuar escribiendo sin fin

```
    1 archivo(s) copiado(s).
```

Cuando hayas terminado de escribir dentro del fichero, pulsa Ctrl + C para salir del fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Pues es prácticamente igual:

```
echo "ejemplo" >> archivo.txt
```

Si el archivo no existe te lo crea

Comment: Hola! En qué difiere esto de la respuesta aceptada?